# Qual a forma correta de passar variáveis no AJAX?

Tags: javascript, ajax

Estou em uma aplicação onde apenas uma das variáveis está sendo recebida pelo arquivo de destino.

**HTML**

```
<input id="txtnome" name="txtnome" type="text" />
    <input id="txtsobre" name="txtsobre" type="text" />
    <br/>
    <button onclick="AlteraConteudo()">Enviar Nome</button>
    <br />
    
    <div id="conteudo">
        
    </div>
```

**AJAX**

```
function AlteraConteudo()
{
    var ajax = AjaxF(); 
    
    ajax.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(ajax.readyState == 4)
        {
            document.getElementById('conteudo').innerHTML = ajax.responseText;
        }
    }
    
    // Variável com os dados que serão enviados ao PHP
    var nome = document.getElementById('txtnome');
    var sobre = document.getElementById('txtsobre');
    
    ajax.open("GET", "retorna_informacoes.php?"nome+" "+sobre, false);
    ajax.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/html");
    ajax.send();
}
```

**Arquivo: retorna_informacoes.php**

```
<?php 
    echo utf8_encode('NOME: '.$_GET['nome'].', seja bem-vindo!!!');
    echo utf8_encode('SOBRE: '.$_GET['sobre'].', seja bem-vindo!!!');
?>
```

O que acontece é que ele só recebe a variável **nome** e ignora **sobre**

Como organizar de forma que eu posso colocar mais variáveis e ele enviar todas?

Comment: @Sam a variável `sobre` continua indo vazia. Coloquei o HTML no texto também para se ter uma visão geral.

Comment: @Sam Coloquei como você postou e retorna o seguinte: NOME: [object HTMLInputElement] SOBRE: [object HTMLInputElement]

Comment: @Sam Coloquei a linha de código que me passou, mas agora aparece a mensagem acima que te mostrei e não aparece nada mais.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130534/discussion-between-gladison-and-sam).